# Merge Symmetrical Difference and Intersection Line

Tags: qgis, vector, merge, syntax

I tried to merge these two types of lines I have from using the geometric tools "Intersection & Symmetrical difference".  They end up being part of the same line and I want to join them together and remain "smart" with their respective attributes.  When I try to merge them with the merge vector command I get the "All layers must have the same geometry type" syntax.  I'm wondering if there is anyway to get through this and to combine the two vectors into one.  I tried to save-as both of the vectors and then combine them that way but when I save-as the symmetrical difference vector then all unwanted vector lines come back. (Look at the second picture to further understand this).

[image]
[image]

Comment: Maybe one of your line layers contains multipart features? You could try using the **Multipart to Singleparts** tool from the menubar `Vector > Geometry Tools > Multipart to Singleparts` on both layers then try to merge again :)